# I want to write merge sort in C++, but got some errors with memory and can't solve it

Tags: c++, mergesort

So there's my code and when I run it I'm getting run out of memory
Could it depend on my computer or it's problem with code?
Algorithm of merge sort I'd read at couple of sites, but nothing helped

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int quicksort (int m[], int left, int right)
 {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int middle = m[(left + right) / 2];
    do{
        while (m[i] <= middle)
            i++;
        while (m[j] >= middle)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            if (m[i] > m[j])
                swap (m[i], m[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }while (i <= j);
    if (left < j)
        quicksort (m, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quicksort (m, i, right);
}

int main ()
{
    int n, i;
    cin>> n;
    int m[n];
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> m[i];
    quicksort (m , 0, n - 1);
    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        cout << m[i] << " ";
}
```

Comment: You say merger sort but your function is called `quicksort`.  Which one are you doing?.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)` -> [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)

Comment: `while (m[i] <= middle)  i++;` why you are so sure that you always can find an element bigger than middle? Same for next loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it should work now, you went beyond the bounds of the array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int quicksort (int m[], int left, int right)
 {
    int i = left;
    int j = right;
    int middle = m[(left + right) / 2];
    do{
        while (m[i] < middle)
            i++;
        while (m[j] > middle)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
            if (m[i] > m[j])
                swap (m[i], m[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }while (i <= j);

    if (left < j)
        quicksort (m, left, j);

    if (i < right)
        quicksort (m, i, right);
}

int main () {
    int n, i;
    cin>> n;
    int m[n + 1];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){cin >> m[i];}
    quicksort (m , 0, n - 1);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){cout << m[i] << " ";}
}
```

Comment: what did you change to make it work? To get anything from this answer I would have to first read the code in the question understand it and then line by line compare it with your code. Please explain what you did.

Comment: In both "while" I'd change non-strict equality to strict equality. Same thing with both "for" in main function

Comment: Post human-readable diffs or prominently mark changed code with comments. Also, try not to break stuff while fixing other stuff (rename quicksort to mergesort in some places but not others, or rename quicksort to mergesort while the procedure in question is, in fact, an implementation of quicksort).